# Connecting with Azure Virtual Machine through Putty via Node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, putty

I know that we can connect Azure VM via putty 
Just out of curiosity, I wanted to know that can I make SSH request from putty, that feeds events for Node.js and node.js further handles the communication? 
or is it possible to Remote access azure VM via node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make ssh connections directly from node.js via [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2).

Comment: There are examples in the module's [readme](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/blob/master/README.md) that cover the most common uses. Without knowing your concrete use case, I don't know what else to suggest.